# SQL - find parent in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I cant express the problem correctly to find the answer online so i'm hoping someone could provide me with a link to a solution because i think this is a rather common task.

We have a hierachy of products and want to determine the parents.
All product names are in the same column and the logic is the following

```
ProductId ProductName
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         ABC
2         ABCD
3         ABCD1
4         ABCD2
```

Result should be

*ABCD1 & ABCD2* are children of *ABCD* and
*ABCD* is child of *ABC*

```
ProductId ProductName ParentName ParentId
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         ABC         NULL       NULL
2         ABCD        ABC        1
3         ABCD1       ABCD       2
...
```

Comment: oh, this will be a really hard task to do. One of the few times where a cursor might be the best answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm.  I think this does what you want:

```
select p.*, pp.ProductName as parentName, pp.ProductId as parentId
from products p outer apply
     (select top (1) pp.*
      from products pp
      where p.ProductName like pp.ProductName + '%' and
            p.ProductId <> pp.ProductId
      order by len(pp.ProductName) desc
     ) pp;
```

Comment: I made a CTE for my table (~200k rows) and this works perfectly.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only 1 character difference.
Then you can LEFT JOIN to the ProductName & one wildcard character '_'

```
SELECT 
 p1.ProductId, 
 p1.ProductName, 
 p2.ProductName AS ParentName, 
 p2.ProductId AS ParentId
FROM Products p1
LEFT JOIN Products p2 ON p1.ProductName LIKE CONCAT(p2.ProductName,'_')
ORDER BY p1.ProductId;
```

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @Products table (
  ProductId INT primary key identity(1,1), 
  ProductName varchar(30) not null, 
  unique (ProductName)
);

insert into @Products (ProductName) values
 ('ABC')
,('ABCD')
,('ABCD1')
,('ABCD2')
;

SELECT 
 p1.ProductId, 
 p1.ProductName, 
 p2.ProductName AS ParentName, 
 p2.ProductId AS ParentId
FROM @Products p1
LEFT JOIN @Products p2 ON p1.ProductName LIKE CONCAT(p2.ProductName,'_')
ORDER BY p1.ProductId;
```

**Result:**

```
ProductId   ProductName ParentName  ParentId
1           ABC         NULL        NULL
2           ABCD        ABC         1
3           ABCD1       ABCD        2
4           ABCD2       ABCD        2
```

If it's possible that there's more than 1 character difference then:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
 p1.ProductId, 
 p1.ProductName, 
 p2.ProductName AS ParentName, 
 p2.ProductId AS ParentId
FROM Products p1
LEFT JOIN Products p2 ON p1.ProductName LIKE CONCAT(p2.ProductName,'_%')
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p1.ProductId ORDER BY LEN(p2.ProductName) DESC);
```

Comment: The char difference can vary between 1-34

Answer (score 1):

No doubt that gordon's answer is best here, but still I gave it a go as well:

```
USE TEMPDB

CREATE TABLE #T (ProductID INT, ProductName VARCHAR (100))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1, 'ABC'), (2, 'ABCD'), (3, 'ABCD1'), (4, 'ABCD2')

WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT T.*,
      T2.ProductID AS ParentID,
      T2.ProductName AS ParentName
FROM #T AS T
CROSS JOIN #T AS T2
WHERE T.ProductName LIKE T2.ProductName + '%'
  AND T.ProductID <> T2.ProductID
)
, CTE2 AS 
(
SELECT TOP 1 T.*,
      NULL AS ParentID,
      NULL AS ParentName
FROM #T AS T
ORDER BY LEN (T.ProductName)
)

SELECT * FROM CTE UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE2 ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: I accepted Gordon's answer bc he was first, it was working and i didnt specify how performant it should be or how many rows we have. 
Your answer turned out to be much more performant. 
I canceled Gordon's solution after about an hour where your's was 7 seconds. Maybe its our fault bc of missing index but i cant tell.

Comment: @jrdev22 Glad that is performs well. I ran one extra test and found one slip up, My query also returns abc as parents for abcd1 and abcd2, which is wrong. You moght want to make some adjustments. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Case with the condition and represent each condition as a new column. You can refer to the syntax https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use Common Table Expression (CTE) to do the job.

```
with product_table (ProductId, ProductName) as
(
    select 1 ProductId         , 'ABC' ProductName union all
    select 2 ProductId         , 'ABCD' ProductName union all
    select 3 ProductId         , 'ABCD1' ProductName union all
    select 4 ProductId         , 'ABCD2' ProductName --union all
)
,product_result (ProductId, ProductName, ParentName, ParentId) as
(
    select ProductId, ProductName, convert(varchar,null) ParentName,     convert(int, null) ParentId
    from product_table 
    where ProductName = 'ABC' --start with 
    union all
    select d.ProductId, d.ProductName, convert(varchar,p.ProductName)     ParentName, p.ProductId ParentId
    from product_table d
    , product_result p
    where d.ProductName like p.ProductName+'_'
)
select *
from product_result
```

The first part **product_table** must be replaced by your own product table. It is used here to generate a tempory dataset.

Your final query will look like:

```
with product_result (ProductId, ProductName, ParentName, ParentId) as
(
    select ProductId, ProductName, convert(varchar,null) ParentName,     convert(int, null) ParentId
    from <YOUR_PRODUCT_TABLE_GOES_HERE> 
    where ProductName = 'ABC' --start with 
    union all
    select d.ProductId, d.ProductName, convert(varchar,p.ProductName)     ParentName, p.ProductId ParentId
    from <YOUR_PRODUCT_TABLE_GOES_HERE> d
    , product_result p
    where d.ProductName like p.ProductName+'_'
)
select *
from product_result
```

CTE is available since SQL2008. for more info [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)